# Disable port Netgear GS728TP

Tags: switch, management, power-over-ethernet

I have some Netgear GS728TP smart switches with some CCTV camera that run over them.

Occasionally these camera's freeze and require the network plug pulling on them to reset (They are PoE)

Some of these switches are in some awkward to get to places so:

Is there a way in the Netgear admin panel to disable / enable switch ports so I can kill the power and essentially reboot the camera without having to climb ladders etc?!

I've hunted through the manuals but no joy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [GS752TP, GS728TP, and GS728TPP Gigabit Smart Switches Software Administration Manual](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/GS728TP/GS752TP_GS728TP_GS728TPP_SWA_3Dec2013.pdf), on page 47:

> Admin Mode. Select whether to enable or disable the ability of the
>   port to deliver power.

It would seem that you can shut off power on the port, wait a few minutes, then re-enable it.

Aside from that, it is not a very good idea to have the switches in awkward places. Network infrastructure devices, like switches and routers, should be racked in data closets, and the cabling should extend back to the data closet.

Comment: Ah! You have a different manual to me. Also, they did not describe what 'Admin mode' meant!!!! Thanks

Comment: Interestingly, this only disables PoE, is there a way to kill the entire port ?

Comment: Data Cabinets, they are up in some roof space due to the design of the building unfortunately. Most of them are in cupboard except for 1/3 of the building with design issues shall we say!

Comment: @AlexHellier, I didn't look for port shut down, but it is on page 76. I just did a search on Google to find this manual.

Comment: Super, thanks. I guess knowing you need to search for Admin mode etc - I'm clearly looking for the wrong things, Thanks again :)

Comment: @AlexHellier, putting devices in roof space usually means that the environment and temperature are not properly controlled, and this can cause problems with the devices. Each device has an operating temperature range which you don't want to go above or below.

Comment: @r yep, I'd love them to be in a better location than they are, but its dictated by the design of the building. The good news is the building is designed as a warehouse, so the area they are in is still heated etc, just hard to get too.